# Getting my Script and CSS pages to work with MVC5 App

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I have started a new MVC5 ASP.Net application. I have been furiously reading all I can and I am not sure I fully understand what it is I am doing wrong.

I have added my javascript pages to the js folder as well as my css to its corresponding folder. I have added this to my App_Start folder in the BundelConfig.cs file:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include("~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/skel").Include("~/Scripts/skel.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/skel").Include("~/Scripts/awards.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/skel").Include("~/Scripts/main.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/skel").Include("~/Scripts/index.js"));
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/main.css", "~/Content/awards.css"));
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/font-awesome.min.css"));
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/fullcalendar.css", "~/Content/fullcalendar.print.css"));
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/noscript.css"));
```

and then added this to Shared _Layout.cshtml file

in the `<head>`:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css/main")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css/font-awesome.min")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css/main")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css/noscript")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/sass/main")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/sass/noscript")
```

At the bottom just above the close of my `<body>` tag:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/index")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.dropotron.min")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.min")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.scrollex.min")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.scrolly.min")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/main")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/moment")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/npm")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/skel")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/util")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/gcal")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/fullcalendar")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

When I run it I don't get any errors but the HTML is just that, HTML. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps my ASP.NET MVC knowledge is a bit out of  date, but this doesn't look like it has much to do with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: What are you expecting the HTML to be, other than HTML?

Comment: How so? And you have to remember that I am trying to explain something that I don't do everyday. I usually do my apps with HTML5 and PHP instead of .NET so that is where I am coming from with this question.

Comment: I am trying to bridge the gab of just plain HTML to the HTML that understands that I am calling it to behave a different way. So when I run the app it not only sees my HTML but it sees and runs the scripts and css that I am calling as well.

Comment: I'm trying to get the app to render the css and scripts so the HTML will act the way I want it to. I can get it to work with bootstrap but I can't get it to work with skel.

Comment: What do I need to do to get my scripts and styles to run in this environment is the best way I can put it.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic here isn't quite right. You're creating multiple bundles all with the same virtual path that are overwriting the previous ones in the `bundles` collection.

Firstly, the idea of bundles is to join multiple JS/CSS files together as a single file. You do this by calling `ScriptBundle()` or `StyleBundle()`, providing a virtual path for that bundle, then using `Include()` to add the files and/or folders.

Secondly, you use the *virtual path* within the View when using `Scripts.Render()` or `Styles.Render()`. Try this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include("~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/skel")
  .Include("~/Scripts/skel.js")
  .Include("~/Scripts/awards.js")
  .Include("~/Scripts/main.js")
  .Include("~/Scripts/index.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
  .Include("~/Content/main.css", "~/Content/awards.css")
  .Include("~/Content/font-awesome.min.css")
  .Include("~/Content/fullcalendar.css", "~/Content/fullcalendar.print.css")
  .Include("~/Content/noscript.css"));

// In the view(s)
@Styles.Render(~/Content/css)
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/skel")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. So I get the bundles now and that makes perfect sense. So I bundled the css just like you said and when I go to compile the view it gives me

Comment: It would be best to use the `edit` button on your question if you want to add some code - comments are not suited to formatted code.

Comment: Line 377:        </div>
Line 378:    </section>
Line 379:    @Styles.Render(~/Content/css)
Line 380:    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
Line 381:    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/skel")

Comment: A compilation error with the @Style.Render(~/Content/css) "/" invalid expression term.

Comment: Nevermind that one I forgot my dang quotes. The main issue is that  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) Exception User unhandled

Comment: That's a little odd. Do you have two sections defined with the same name?

Comment: No just the ones that we have been talking about and the two Jquery ones that Visual Studio adds when the initial app is built. But neither of them are called the same thing.

Comment: Ok I deleted @Styles.Render(~/Content/css)
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/skel")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

Comment: from every page except _layout and I don't get the error anymore but still nothing but just plain html. It just isn't calling the javascript and css like it needs to.

Comment: If you view the source you should see the `<script>` and `<link>` tags being generated by the bundles. If you paste the URL in to the browser from them, do you see valid CSS/JS code?

Comment: If I add the  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/skel")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) to the Index it gives me the Exception User-Unhandled System.Web.HttpException: 'The file "~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml" cannot be requested directly because it calls the "RenderSection" method.'

Comment: If `Index.cshtml` is the View - that's the issue. `RenderSection` should be placed in layouts. Hopefully this guide should help: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor It's for MVC3, but the principles still apply

Comment: No links but at least it is seeing some scripts     <script src="/Scripts/awards.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/main.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/index.js"></script>

Comment: I just don't understand why it is showing those and not the css or the other scripts that were bundled there.

Comment: I'll keep reading this. Thank you for that and I will give you an update as soon as I have one.

Comment: What an incredible overview tutorial that was. I understand a ton more now thank you. I have leveled up in .NET. Now I am on to the next level of questions so thank you.